# Pandas - Get keys associated with an entry

Tags: python, pandas

I have an square correlation matrix:

```
a0 a1 a2 ……… an
b1
b2
……
bn
```

I want to pass the keys from the multi-index of this matrix to another function, so want to form a list of tuples of all key pairs (that pass a filtration function, say (e >= .95)

```
[('KEYA', 'KEYB')]
```

Is there a function built in to pandas that lets me accomplish this? RTMF has failed me for a couple hours on this.

Comment: What are `"KEYA"` and `"KEYB"`? Are those variable/column names from either of the axes? Also, +1 for using RTMF instead of RTFM :)

Comment: Generally a matrix would be stored in numpy, not pandas.

Comment: @not_a_robot variable/column names…since this is a correlation matrix it's the same list of n vars running both ways…we'll just use the lower triangle matrix here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a filtration then you can first stack your dataframe and then filter it down to just the values you want and then force the index to a list.

```
df1 = df.stack()
df_final = df1[df1 > .95]
df_final.index.tolist()
```

#### Creating fake data and testing

```
np.random.seed(12)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,10))

df1 = df.stack()
df_final = df1[df1 > .95]
df_final.index.tolist()
```

Would result in

```
[(0, 8), (3, 3), (3, 5), (4, 1), (4, 3), (9, 0)]
```

`df_final` would look like this:

```
0  8    0.956949
3  3    0.978058
   5    0.950314
4  1    0.995138
   3    0.962597
9  0    0.957417
```

Comment: oh my god that's elegant